# Table Column Formatting

Tags: css, css-tables, col

I'm trying to format a column in a `<table/>` using a `<col/>` element. I can set `background-color`, `width`, etc., but can't set the `font-weight`. Why doesn't it work?

```
<table>
    <col style="font-weight:bold; background-color:#CCC;">
    <col>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only format the following using CSS on the `<col>` element:

- background-color
- border
- width
- visibility

This [page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html) has more info.

Herb is right - it's better to style the `<td>`'s directly.  What I do is the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
   #mytable tr > td:first-child { color: red;} /* first column */
   #mytable tr > td:first-child + td { color: green;} /* second column */
   #mytable tr > td:first-child + td + td { color: blue;} /* third column */
   </style>
   </head>
   <body> 
   <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <td>text 1</td>
      <td>text 2</td>
      <td>text 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text 4</td>
      <td>text 5</td>
      <td>text 6</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

This won't work in IE however.

Comment: That just looks to me like you're over-engineering the problem a bit. Why not create a "red", "green" and "blue" class? That would work everywhere, and be much more intuitive than advanced CSS selectors.

Comment: Yep your right the CSS selectors are ugly :)  But I personally would prefer ugly CSS selectors than having to add a class attribute to each table cell, especially if you have a static table (i.e., no server side generation involved) that has lots of cells.

Comment: Alas, this will break semantically for colspans. That's the whole point of the `col` and `colgroup` elements, why the heck can't you set the color using them?!

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is to apply your styling directly to the `<td>` tags. I've never used the `<col>` tag, but most browsers let you apply formatting at the `<table>` and `<td>`/`<th>` level, but not at an intermediate level. For example if you have

```
<table>
    <tr class="Highlight">
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then this CSS won't work

```css
tr.Highlight { background:yellow }
```

but this will

```css
tr.Highlight td { background:yellow }
```

Also: I assume your code above is just for demonstration purposes and you're not actually going to apply styles inline.

Comment: This method works fine. I was just trying to avoid putting a <code>class</code> attribute for every first-column <code>td</code>.

Answer (score 3):

You might have just needed this:

```
tr td:first-child label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried applying the style through a CSS class?

The following appears to work:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  .xx {
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-align: right;
}

<table border="1">
  <col width="150" />
  <col width="50" class="xx" />
  <col width="80" />
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Reference for the col element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/col)

Comment: Please note that IE (Quirks Mode) does allow for color to work. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html.  But this is not a solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through this as I was attempting to style a table such that the first column would be bold text and the the other four columns would be normal text.
Using col tag seemed like the way to go but while I could set the widths of the columns with the width attribute the font-weight: bold wouldn't work
Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the solution.
By styling all the td elements `td {font-weight: bold;}` and then using an adjacent sibling selector to select columns 2-5 and style them back to normal `td + td {font-weight: normal;}`
Voila, alls good :)

Answer (score -1):

A `col` tag must be inside of a `colgroup` tag, This may be something to do with the problem.

Comment: As Andy said, but want to make sure it's attached to the original (and he can't comment yet). col DOES NOT have to be in colgroup.
<a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.2">W3C Reference</a>