# Select first column of table having rowspan

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I have a table with `rowspan` in first cells of row. I want to select first cells. When I select first child, in some rows after `rowspan`, first child going to be cells that are not in first row.

**How to select just first column of table?**

Here is my JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/qw78pcud/

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
}
table tr td:first-child{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Bank Name</th>
            <th>SWIFT BIG</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>Deutsche Bank Trust Company Americas, New Your</td>
            <td>BKTRUS33</td>
            <td>USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>Deutsche Bank AG</td>
            <td>DEUTDEFF</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Austria</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Raiffeisen Bank International AG</td>
            <td rowspan="2">RZBAATWW</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>USD</td></tr>
        
        
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="5">Netherlands</td>
            <td rowspan="5">Demir - Halk Bank (Nederland) N.V.</td>
            <td rowspan="5">DHBNNL2R</td>
            <td >EUR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>USD</td></tr>
        <tr><td>GBP</td></tr>
        <tr><td>CHF</td></tr>
        <tr><td>JPY</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I used following selector but it selects last childs after rowspan as jsfiddle shows

```
table tr td:first-child{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Note: I can't set class or id to table elements. I need to access with css.

**Edit: What can we do in This case?** http://jsfiddle.net/qw78pcud/6

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}
table tr td:first-child:not(:only-child) {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Bank Name</th>
            <th>SWIFT BIG</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>Deutsche Bank Trust Company Americas, New Your</td>
            <td>BKTRUS33</td>
            <td>USD</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>Deutsche Bank AG</td>
            <td>DEUTDEFF</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Austria</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Raiffeisen Bank International AG</td>
            <td rowspan="2">RZBAATWW</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>USD</td></tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="5">Netherlands</td>
            <td rowspan="5">Demir - Halk Bank (Nederland) N.V.</td>
            <td rowspan="5">DHBNNL2R</td>
            <td >EUR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>USD</td></tr>
        <tr><td>GBP</td></tr>
        <tr><td>CHF</td></tr>
        <tr><td>JPY</td></tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="10">Russia</td>
            <td rowspan="3">CB “Garanti Bank – Moscow” (ZAO)</td>
            <td rowspan="3">GABMRUMM</td>
            <td >EUR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>USD</td></tr>
        <tr><td>RUB</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Sberbank of Russia </td>
            <td rowspan="2">SABRRUMM</td>
            <td>USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>RUB</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">JSCB “Yapi Kredi Bank Moscow" (CJSC)</td>
            <td rowspan="3">YKBMRUMM</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>USD</td></tr>
        <tr><td>RUB</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">ZAO Raiffeisenbank </td>
            <td rowspan="2">RZBMRUMM</td>
            <td>USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>RUB</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could achieve that by using a combination of [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) pseudo-classes as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qw78pcud/4/)**

```css
table tr td:first-child:not(:only-child) {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This would exclude the cells that are the **only child** of their parents - the rows.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Couldn't think of nested selectors and didn't know about :not().

Comment: what we can do if there are more than one child in rows that shouldn't be selected? jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qw78pcud/6/. Could we select row that has four childs instead only-child(something like :four-childed)

Comment: @Erlan Unfortunately there is **no general** way to select only the first **visual** cells (which are not necessarily the first child `<td>` in the markup logically). In this complex situations, you could use [`<colgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) element to apply some styles to the first column. But [there are some restrictions](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/colgroup).You [can only control](http://stackoverflow.com/a/159848/1725764) `background-color, border, width, visibility` properties **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/qw78pcud/7/)**.